# Problems integrating bootstrap elements with a css template

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I downloaded a template for a website. The template is just html and css, it doesnt use any framework.

Im working with angular, and when i try to implement some bootstrap´s forms on the template, the website turns disordered.

What can i do?

Comment: What can you do... what? If you want to implement st. from bootstrap, download&link bootstrap and modify your HTML.

Comment: Make sure your class names and styles aren't conflicting with bootstraps

Comment: Could you share an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap will have dependencies on Angular, Try to fix the dependencies.